# Ajax not allowing View rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, redirect

I have a couple of variations on the ajax depending on the flow of interactions on the page. But it's only the variables that changes. here is one of them:

```
$('#btn_skickaEnkel').bind('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Contact/IntresseAnmälan/',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                Namn: $('#namn').val(),
                Mail: $('#mail').val(),
                Info: $('#meddelande').val(),
                Nivå: $('#nivå').find(":selected").text(),
                IsEnkel: true,
                Telefon: $('#nr').val(),
                ID: function () {
                    var url = window.location.pathname;
                    var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    return id;
                }
            },
            traditional: true
        });
    });
```

In my controller i am unable to redirect or return a different view. At this point the data from JSON is no longer relevant because it's already been saved to DB.

My Controller:

```
 public ActionResult IntresseAnmälan(BokningContainer bokning)
    {
        db = new DbContext();

        //Saving some data to database(removed)

        //Just determening the state of container obj.
        if (bokning.IsEnkel)
        {

            //Geting som information from db (removed)

            //Creating a mail (removed)
            email.Send(bokning.Namn, bokning.Mail, body);

        }
        else
        {

        }

        //db.SaveChanges(); 

        //This part is not working, I think it's beacuase of the Ajax
        return View("IntresseAnmälan"); 
    }
```

The view is not rendered and I think it's related to the ajax. The view is simply not rendered. Is there some way to force returning it and ignoring the ajax? As I said the data is no longer needed because the content is already saved to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot render view on ajax call,simply you can use form post method or just redirect it to desired action on "succcess" of ajax call as below:

```
$('#btn_skickaEnkel').bind('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Contact/IntresseAnmälan/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            Namn: $('#namn').val(),
            Mail: $('#mail').val(),
            Info: $('#meddelande').val(),
            Nivå: $('#nivå').find(":selected").text(),
            IsEnkel: true,
            Telefon: $('#nr').val(),
            ID: function () {
                var url = window.location.pathname;
                var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                return id;
            }
        },
        traditional: true,
        success: function(result) {
             window.location.href = '@Url.Action("action", "Controller")';
       } 
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and it doesn't solve my problem. Even without the -> success: implementation i still get to the controller. I even render the _Layout.cshtml but when I get to the @RenderBody() part in _Layout.cshtml it's simply not rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't believe my eyes when I figured out this "Bugg". The problem was that I, at some point, changed the submit to a button. So the form was never submiting. Well, at least I learnt a bit about views and Ajax.

Sorry for taking your time.